# Brake fluid ran dry (ABS system)

Tags: brakes, dodge, brake-fluid, durango, drum-brakes

I have a 2000 Dodge Durango with an ABS system. Earlier this week, I realized that one of my wheel cylinders had a leak, and I ran out of brake fluid (good thing it was not while driving). Anyways, I have replaced the wheel cylinder, and I have bled it.

That being said, I believe I heard somewhere that when an ABS system runs dry, it needs to be electronically bled to get all of the air out of the system. Am I remembering this correctly?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yes, you need to activate the ABS to bleed the pump, either electronically or.. dangerously.

Answer (score 1):

yes there is additional bleeding required. From a shop manual:

[image]